# Java - Rollup Order quanity for each duplicate order in a list

Tags: java, algorithm

With the below provided code, what I'm trying to achieve is:
I have orders coming in and if the list has orders for same product - identified by product name, i have to increase quantity of the first order and remove other similar orders.

Examples of similar Orders in the below list: P3 and P4.

But this approach results in exception and wondering if you guys can suggest any other approach to it.

This is an example list and my list in general would contain 800 Or More Orders.

```
public class RollUpLogic {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    orderList.add(new Order("P1", 1));
    orderList.add(new Order("P2", 1));
    orderList.add(new Order("P3", 1));
    orderList.add(new Order("P3", 1));
    orderList.add(new Order("P3", 1));
    orderList.add(new Order("P4", 1));
    orderList.add(new Order("P4", 2));


    //if same product ordered, Rollup the quantity and remove duplicate orders

        Iterator<Order> iterator = orderList.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Order order = iterator.next();
            int firstIndex = orderList.indexOf(order);
            int lastIndex = orderList.lastIndexOf(order);
            while(firstIndex!=lastIndex) {
                //+1 qty of firstindex order
                order.setProductQTY(order.getProductQTY()+1);

                //remove order at lastIndex
                orderList.remove(lastIndex); //throws concurrent modification exception
               lastIndex = orderList.lastIndexOf(order);
            }
        }
}
}


class Order{
private String productName;
private int productQTY;

public Order(String productName, int productQTY) {
    super();
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productQTY = productQTY;
}

public int getProductQTY() {
    return productQTY;
}
public void setProductQTY(int productQTY) {
    this.productQTY = productQTY;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((productName == null) ? 0 : productName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Order other = (Order) obj;
    if (productName == null && other.productName != null) {
            return false;
    } else if (!productName.equals(other.productName))
        return false;
    return true;
}   
}
```

Comment: Show us a stack trace!

Comment: Exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at RollUpLogic.main(RollUpLogic.java:24)`

Comment: I think you can remove duplicates pretty easy in java 8 by using Streams. For example : orderList.stream()
    .distinct();

Comment: @KevinPaton sorry, i should have clarified, we are still on Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a new list instead of modifying the existing one.  You cannot use `Collection.remove` (or `add`, etc) while iterating on a collection, that's what causes the exception.

For efficiency, you might use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

```
LinkedHashMap<Order> orderMap = new LinkedHashMap<Order>();
for (Order order: orderList) {
    String orderName = order.getProductName();
    if (orderMap.containsKey(orderName)) {
        Order existing = orderMap.get(orderName);
        existing.setProductQty(existing.getProductQty() + order.getProductQty());
    } else {
        orderMap.put(orderName, order);
    }
}

// optionally, copy back to the list
orderList.clear();
for (Order order: orderMap.values()) {
    orderList.add(order);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create another list with grouped orders.
It is not very an issue for memory since you will add references.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to achieve is basically a MultiMap from String (productName) to int (quantity). Why don't you use one (e.g. [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a nice general implementation, or you could use a [trove](https://bitbucket.org/robeden/trove/) TObjectIntHashMap with its `adjustOrPutValue` method)?

Comment: I have restrictions on what external libraries i can add to my work projects. So, wouldn't be able to do it. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: If you cannot use an external libary, Jean Logeart's answer is the one for you. Btw. you can keep the Map from the beginning and update it online, which will probably be faster than first creating the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are some concurrent implementations that you could also use in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, Integer>` in which you keep track of the quantity of items for each product name:

```
Map<String, Integer> productQuantity = new HashMap<>();
for(Order o : orderList) {
    Integer q = productQuantity.get(o.getProductName());
    int newQ = o.getProductQTY() + (q == null ? 0 : q.intValue());
    productQuantity.put(o.getProductName(), newQ);
}
```

Then you can convert this map to a `List`` of updated orders.